# Set diagonal triangle in pandas DataFrame to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given the below dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

I'd like to produce the following result:

```
df([[ NaN,  1,  2,  3],
    [ NaN,  NaN,  6,  7],
    [ NaN,  NaN,  NaN, 11],
    [ NaN,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN]])
```

So far I've tried using `np.tril_indicies`, but it only works with a df turned back into a numpy array, and it only works for integer assignments (not np.nan):

```
il1 = np.tril_indices(4)
a[il1] = 0
```

gives:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

...which is almost what I'm looking for, but barfs at assigning NaN:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

while:

```
df[il1] = 0
```

gives:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So if I want to fill the bottom triangle of a dataframe with NaN, does it 1) have to be a numpy array, or can I do this with pandas directly? And 2) Is there a way to fill bottom triangle with NaN rather than using `numpy.fill_diagonal` and incrementing the offset row by row down the whole DataFrame?

Another failed solution:
Filling the diagonal of np array with zeros, then masking on zero and reassigning to np.nan. It converts zero values above the diagonal as NaN when they should be preserved as zero!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need cast to `float`  `a`, because `type` of `NaN` is `float`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4).astype(float)
print (a)
[[  0.   1.   2.   3.]
 [  4.   5.   6.   7.]
 [  8.   9.  10.  11.]
 [ 12.  13.  14.  15.]]


il1 = np.tril_indices(4)
a[il1] = np.nan
print (a)
[[ nan   1.   2.   3.]
 [ nan  nan   6.   7.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  11.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['a','b','c','d'])
print (df)
    a    b    c     d
0 NaN  1.0  2.0   3.0
1 NaN  NaN  6.0   7.0
2 NaN  NaN  NaN  11.0
3 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: and if my data is originally in a dataframe, then move it into np array, then back into a dataframe?  no way to do this in pandas itself?

Comment: pandas solution is similar `Divakar` - `df = df.mask(np.arange(4)[:,None] >= np.arange(4))`

Comment: use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

Comment: `np.nan` can be omit, becasue it is by default

Answer (score 6):

An approach using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
m,n = df.shape
df[:] = np.where(np.arange(m)[:,None] >= np.arange(n),np.nan,df)
```

Sample run -

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]: 
    a   b   c   d
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15

In [94]: m,n = df.shape

In [95]: df[:] = np.where(np.arange(m)[:,None] >= np.arange(n),np.nan,df)

In [96]: df
Out[96]: 
    a    b    c     d
0 NaN  1.0  2.0   3.0
1 NaN  NaN  6.0   7.0
2 NaN  NaN  NaN  11.0
3 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thanks, but just out of curiosity, what is the `[:]` in `df[:]` doing?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew It's assigning all values from the Right Hand Side into df. So, for example : `df[:] = 1`, would make all values in `df` as `1s`.