# Grouping dataframe based on consecutive occurrence of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas array which has one column which is either true or false (titled 'condition' in the example below). I would like to group the array by consecutive true or false values. I have tried to use pandas.groupby but haven't succeeded using that method, albeit I think that's down to my lack of understanding. An example of the dataframe can be found below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print df
print df
index condition   H  t
0          1  2    1.1
1          1  7    1.5
2          0  1    0.9
3          0  6.5  1.6
4          1  7    1.1
5          1  9    1.8
6          1  22   2.0
```

Ideally the output of the program would be something along the lines of what can be found below. I was thinking of using some sort of 'grouping' method to make it easier to call each set of results but not sure if this is the best method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
index condition   H  t group
0          1  2    1.1  1
1          1  7    1.5  1
2          0  1    0.9  2
3          0  6.5  1.6  2
4          1  7    1.1  3 
5          1  9    1.8  3
6          1  22   2.0  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're dealing with 0/1s, here's another alternative using `diff` + `cumsum` -

```
df['group'] = df.condition.diff().abs().cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int) + 1    
df

       condition     H    t  group
index                             
0              1   2.0  1.1      1
1              1   7.0  1.5      1
2              0   1.0  0.9      2
3              0   6.5  1.6      2
4              1   7.0  1.1      3
5              1   9.0  1.8      3
6              1  22.0  2.0      3
```

If you don't mind floats, this can be made a little faster.

```
df['group'] = df.condition.diff().abs().cumsum() + 1
df.loc[0, 'group'] = 1
df

   index  condition     H    t  group
0      0          1   2.0  1.1    1.0
1      1          1   7.0  1.5    1.0
2      2          0   1.0  0.9    2.0
3      3          0   6.5  1.6    2.0
4      4          1   7.0  1.1    3.0
5      5          1   9.0  1.8    3.0
6      6          1  22.0  2.0    3.0
```

Here's the version with numpy equivalents -

```
df['group'] = 1
df.loc[1:, 'group'] = np.cumsum(np.abs(np.diff(df.condition))) + 1
df


       condition     H    t  group
index                             
0              1   2.0  1.1      1
1              1   7.0  1.5      1
2              0   1.0  0.9      2
3              0   6.5  1.6      2
4              1   7.0  1.1      3
5              1   9.0  1.8      3
6              1  22.0  2.0      3
```

---

On my machine, here are the timings -

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df['group'] = df.condition.diff().abs().cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int) + 1 
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop

%%timeit
df['group'] = df.condition.diff().abs().cumsum() + 1
df.loc[0, 'group'] = 1

10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop

%%timeit
df['group'] = 1
df.loc[1:, 'group'] = np.cumsum(np.abs(np.diff(df.condition))) + 1

10 loops, best of 3: 21.4 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit df['group'] = df['condition'].ne(df['condition'].shift()).cumsum()
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: @jezrael Okay sorry, yes I changed it. The numpy version is faster on my computer.

Comment: This worked great for me. I used the first example as I want to keep my array as a pandas data frame. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: So performance is not important? I am a bit surprised `diff` slowier solution is better as shift...

Comment: @RodrigoProdohl You're welcome. If you find my answer is too slow, take another look at jezraels' solution though our answers will perform almost equal on smaller data.

Comment: @RodrigoProdohl - but it is up you what solution use, sure ;)

Comment: @jezrael From my experience, [not always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545491/4909087)!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - yes, but maybe OP dont want numpy complicated solution, so use slowier and easier one in link.

Comment: Exactly, it depends on OP.

Comment: Both solutions worked great and I really appreciate all the responses I get on my questions so thank you both :)

Answer (score 4):

Compare with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column and then use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['group'] = df['condition'].ne(df['condition'].shift()).cumsum()
print (df)
       condition     H    t  group
index                             
0              1   2.0  1.1      1
1              1   7.0  1.5      1
2              0   1.0  0.9      2
3              0   6.5  1.6      2
4              1   7.0  1.1      3
5              1   9.0  1.8      3
6              1  22.0  2.0      3
```

Detail:

```
print (df['condition'].ne(df['condition'].shift()))
index
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: condition, dtype: bool
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)


In [54]: %timeit df['group'] = df['condition'].ne(df['condition'].shift()).cumsum()
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit df['group'] = df.condition.diff().abs().cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int) + 1
10 loops, best of 3: 24.5 ms per loop

In [56]: %%timeit
    ...: df['group'] = 1
    ...: df.loc[1:, 'group'] = np.cumsum(np.abs(np.diff(df.condition))) + 1
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 26.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you.